# Filter out dataframe rows where specific columns have zeroes (R)

Tags: r

suppose I've got a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Cat = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  S1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  S2 = c(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2),
  S3 = c(-3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 5),
  S4 = c(0, -5, 5, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

I want to remove any rows where S1, S2, S3, and S4 are all zeroes, so that I'd only be left with Cat A, B, C, and F. I can't simply use use a row sum because that would also wrongly remove Cat A (since 3 + -3 = 0). Note that in the real data, there are 36 "S*x*" columns with names that will change every month. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Surely this search would have identified a method. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+remove+rows+all+zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(keep = apply(across(-Cat), 1, function(x) !all(x == 0))) %>%
  filter(keep == TRUE) %>%
  select(-keep)

  Cat S1 S2 S3 S4
1   A  0  3 -3  0
2   B  0  0  3 -5
3   C  0  0  2  5
4   F  0  2  5  0
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums(df[-1] == 0)` to count the number of 0s in each row, excluding the first column.

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] == 0) < (nrow(df) - 1), ]
#   Cat S1 S2 S3 S4
# 1   A  0  3 -3  0
# 2   B  0  0  3 -5
# 3   C  0  0  2  5
# 6   F  0  2  5  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
zero_cols <- c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")

df[!apply(df[,zero_cols], 1, function(x) all(x == 0)),]
```

Output:

```
#   Cat S1 S2 S3 S4
# 1   A  0  3 -3  0
# 2   B  0  0  3 -5
# 3   C  0  0  2  5
# 6   F  0  2  5  0
```